# Android show dialog from background thread in any activity of application

Tags: android, multithreading, dialog, background

I tried to look clear answer for it but wasn't able to find it anywhere. I am running background thread in main activity that checks for certain variable and if it is true it should show alert dialog. I also want this dialog to show up on any focused activity of the application. I tried it by adding Looper.prepare() and Looper.loop() to the thread but it does not work properly and it affects while() loop that I use to check variable in that thread. Can anyone please help me in finding out what is the best way to implement this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you construct the background thread using the main/ui thread, you can create a `Handler` in the constructor.  When you want to run some code on the main/ui thread, you simply `Handler.post(Runnable r)` with a runnable to the ui thread.

If your background thread is not being constructed on the ui/main thread, you can use a BroadcastIntent to and a BroadcastReceiver pattern to send messages between your background thread and your foreground activities.  This is especially useful if you are switching foreground activities during the useful life of your background thread.

Comment: Hi wouldn't it only show up dialog only when main activity is focused?.. I am sorry I am new to this so don't have much in-depth knowledge about it.

Comment: For the first method, yes.  For the second method, you'd just implement the broadcast listener in each of your activities.  Alternatively, you could create an abstract class which extends Activity and has code to handle the broadcast listener and put the runnable on to the ui thread using [runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)).  My guess is that you will find this mechanism far easier to manage then re-implementing the broadcast listener.

Comment: Is it the best practice performance-wise to have broadcast listener?

Comment: Its a really good practice from a perspective of decoupling your service from your activities.  Performance wise, I don't know why it would have a significant performance issue.  The mechanism is like a mailbox-delivery setup which are usually written to be pretty efficient.  You can also turn the listener on and off as you need it.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try creating an implementation of `Runnable` and passing that to a `View`'s `post()` method.

```
final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        //code to display dialog
    }
}

final View view = findViewById(R.id.XYZ);
view.post(r);
```

This will run the `Runnable` on the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i can see two approaches. The first one is a dirty but quick:
You can extend `TimerTask` and `Handler` classes. `YourTimerTask` will check variable and send a `Message` to `YourHandler`. `YourHandler` should override `handleMessage` and show a dialog.

The second one might be an overkill, but still. Android is *event-based*. It means that system gives you an opportunity to create your own events and handle it. So, you can start a `Service`, which will check your variable and send a `Broadcast` (can be local). In your activity you have to create your own `BroadcastReceiver` and register it. This receiver will handle a message.